# CSS 3 dropdown menu , child elements not coming properly

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, position

I have a drop down menu created with CSS. The menu is in [Dropdown Menu](http://7sisters.in/lab/dropdown/). The problem is that when I try to access the child element , they are not coming properly. I have given some margin between the parent and the child elements,and when the mouse cursor points to that gap, the drop down menu hides. Is there any way I can maintain a margin and still able to see the child list,like in jquery.

Comment: Use `padding` instead of `margin`

Comment: Thanks. Its working but since I gave a background to child elements, it looks very odd.

Answer (score 1):

As Morpheus suggested, set the padding on the container div. To get the margin effect, move the background style to the child div.